# css style to fix/float the input panel in the left side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My page designs with a header, a footer, a left panel with inputs, a right panel with outputs using bootstrap 4.

The left panel is much shorter than the right panel. The height of left panel might be higher than window height or shorter than window height. See the image below for an example of my layout of whole page.

I want to update this design to fix/float the left panel when the right panel scroll downing to allow users can change some inputs, i.e. users can always see the left panel.

- The left panel is fixed/float at the top of window if the height is less the window height.
- The left panel is fixed/float at the bottom of window if the height is more than window height.

Not sure I phrase my question clear. Let me know for clarification.

[image]

This is a minimum example to reproduce my layout.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header style="height:100px;background-color:#ffd800"></header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color:#00ff21;min-height:500px;height:1000px;">
      </div>

      <div class="col-8" style="background-color:#00ffff;min-height:1000px;height:3000px;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer style="height:100px;background-color:#b6ff00"></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
.col-4 {
  position: sticky !important;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
}
```

This way the sidebar will always be shown. But if you want to stick sidebar to bottom, I think you can't do this without javascript.

Note that I used `important` to override your inline style.